# Scrolling floating/sliding sidebar issue

Tags: javascript, css

I've looked through all stuff in here related to what I'm facing, but still can't get it fixed.

What I'm trying to do:

1. Get a sidebar navigation to float as the user scrolls up/down the page.
2. To have the sidebar centrally stopping so that all elements can be seen and clicked.

What I'm getting:

1. Sidebar follows scrolling just fine when scrolling down (centralised view), but when scrolling up, only half of the sidebar is displayed when the page is scrolled up too fast.
2. When scrolling down the page, the sidebar will push the footer further below without end.
3. The sidebar will not lock back into its original position when the page is scrolled all the way up from the bottom. There seems to be a slight gap.

[**Demo Link**](http://demo.blufroge.com/index.php?m=main&c=show_shopping_details_all&subCateId=2)

Here is the script (modded from the generous Jordon Mears):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function animate_box() {  
var offset = -15; /* set this to the starting margin-top in the css */  
var element = document.getElementById('animate_box'); 

if(element) {  
    var top = Number(String(element.style.marginTop).substring(0,String(element.style.marginTop).indexOf('px')));

    try {  
        if(document.body.scrollTop > 500) {  
            var difference = (document.body.scrollTop + offset);
        } else if(document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {  
            var difference = (document.documentElement.scrollTop + offset);

        } else {  
            var difference = offset;  
        }  
    } catch(e) {  
        var difference = offset;  
    }  

    difference = difference - top;  

    if(difference > 200) {  
        element.style.marginTop = (top + Math.abs(Math.ceil(difference / 30))) + 'px';  
    } else if(difference < 190) {  
        element.style.marginTop = (top - Math.abs(Math.ceil(difference / 30))) + 'px';  
    }  
}  
}  
window.setInterval(animate_box, 50);
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you wanna animate? Why can't you use `position: fixed;`?

Comment: How exactly do you want it to float? Haha, I was gonna say the same @PraveenKumar

Comment: @Andy Any basic web developer would ask this, if the OP is not going to code this for `IE 6`.

Comment: True @PraveenKumar Main reason why I asked about how he wants it to float is because if he's using Javascript, then there must be some floaty effect he wants, cuz this should have been easy to implement otherwise.

Comment: My apologies, silly of me not to include the sample site: http://demo.blufroge.com/index.php?m=main&c=show_shopping_details_all&subCateId=2

Comment: See the sidebar there? So the 'animated' that I mentioned is just that: it moves according to where the user scrolls. Sorry, am just an amateur coder >.<

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different approach:

- save the starting position of the element (.offset().top)
- when scroll happens:
- if the window scroll offset (.scrollTop()) is more than the starting position, then change the position of the sidebar to "fixed" with "top: 0"
- if it goes under the starting position change it back to static (default position).

Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var backup_position_toolbar = $('#sidebar').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ( $('#sidebar').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() &lt; 0) $('#sidebar').addClass('fixed');
        if ( $(window).scrollTop() &lt; backup_position_toolbar ) $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
    });
});
```

Note that I use a "fixed" class defined as follows:
    .fixed {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }

This makes the menu more usable.
If you want to block the sidebar at a certain point you can add a little more logic (ie when bottom is too close).
In this way you don't need to set numeric values (500, 200 etc).

HOWEVER if you want something more with no effort try bootstrap with "affix" (look at the left menu, is what you want)
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix

Comment: Thanks! I'll go experiment with it :)